# Rails condition in Model in order to sort results using sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, model

currently I am using solr for the search in the database.
I want is to sort that by a date.

Problem: The date is serialized as array in the database, since it can be localized.

My logic would then look for a country specific entry and - if not there, use the default one.

So it can look like this:

```
 [{"DE" => "localizeddate"}, {"EN" => "localizeddate"}, ...]
```

or like this:

```
[{"default" => "defaultdate"}]
```

Now, my class looks like this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
serialize :colors, Array
serialize :variants, Array
serialize :images, Array
serialize :sizes, Array
serialize :online_from, Array


searchable do

    text :dw_productid, :display_name, :short_description       
    time :online_from # This is the date that solr will pick up for sorting
end
end
```

The problem is that I cannot just pass `:online_from` to solr.
How can I insert a logic here? Do I do that in the model??

Thanks

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it:

So inside the searchable method you can add `time :something do` in order to do more stuff with it.

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

```
serialize :colors, Array
serialize :variants, Array
serialize :images, Array
serialize :sizes, Array
serialize :online_from, Array



searchable do

    text :dw_productid, :display_name, :short_description       

    # Sort products according to the online from date
    time :online_from do |onlinefromdate|
        if onlinefromdate.online_from[0] != nil
            @onlinefromdate = onlinefromdate.online_from[0]["DE"] if onlinefromdate.online_from[0]["DE"] != nil
            @onlinefromdate = onlinefromdate.online_from[0]["default"] if onlinefromdate.online_from[0]["default"] != nil
            @onlinefromdate = onlinefromdate.online_from[0][0]
        else
            @onlinefromdate = Date.parse('2001-02-03')
        end
    end
end
end
```